# Remove or move only selected files with SFTP protocol using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, sftp, file-rename, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to develop a simple SFTP file transferring project with following operations

1. Upload
2. Download
3. Move files within the remote server
4. Remove files

While uploading in `session.PutFiles()` we have a property called `transferOptions.FileMask` to filter the files.

But I didn't see anything of that kind in `session.MoveFile()` and in `session.RemoveFiles()`

My question is what should I do if I need to move/remove only selected files?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl not at one shot. I just need to do the operations in the selected files only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles) accepts a [file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_wildcard).

So you can do:

```
session.RemoveFiles("/home/user/*.txt");
```

It's the same as with the [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles). The [`TransferOptions.FileMask`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions) is actually intended for advanced selections, like when you want to select files recursively, or when you want to exclude certain types of files.

```
session.PutFiles(@"c:\toupload\*.txt", "/home/user/");
```

With the `TransferOption.FileMask`, WinSCP would upload all matching files recursively. While with a simple file mask as the argument to the `.PutFiles`, it's not recursive.

---

The [`Session.MoveFile`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_movefile) actually supports the file mask in its first argument too, *though it's an undocumented feature.*

A proper way would be to list remote directory, select desired files and call the `Session.MoveFile` for each.

See [Listing files matching wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_listing_files_matching_wildcard). It's a PowerShell example, but mapping it to C# should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MartinPrikryl
Removing files is working perfectly fine.
But while moving files exception is thrown

session.MoveFile("/upload/Folder1", "/upload/Folder1/Archive");

Comment: That command does not make sense, you are moving a folder into its own subfolder, that's not possible. I assume you actually wanted to move files from that folder (not the folder itself) into its subfolder. That would be `session.MoveFile("/upload/Folder1/*", "/upload/Folder1/Archive/")` (note the trailing slash). Though that would try to move the "Archive" folder to itself too, and that would fail again. If you can select the files using extension to differentiate them from the folder, please do. If not, you have to use the solution suggested in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your help. I found the resolution soon after posting the question :)

As per the documentation the syntax is `MoveFile(string sourcePath, string targetPath)`
I guess It should be `MoveFile(string fileName,string targetPath)`, because it worked for me.
I was trying to move the files one by one to the sub-folder

Comment: What do you find confusing about `sourcePath`?

Comment: i was giving the source path alone as "/upload/Folder1/"

Comment: That's would be a (source) **directory** path, not source path. Source path is a path to the file you want to move.